# Has anyone used the mmKnapsack function from the FLSSS R package, and received sub-optimal solutions?

Tags: r, optimization, knapsack-problem

I've just tried using the mmKnapsack function to solve a multi-dimensional knapsack problem in R.
I noticed that the solution seemed a bit suspect, so I tried a very simple 2-d problem:[the 2-d problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyvNB.png). It returned an optimal profit of 720, which I can easily see is not the optimal profit of the 2-d problem(the optimal profit is 740). It returns a solution of items 2 and 1 [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iNAI.png), but the optimal solution is items 1, 4 and 6.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFJ1l.png) is the code I ran

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get help on this site, you should include a portion of your data and your code, something that can be easily copy-pasted (no pics of code or data). Also, this site is focused on programming issues, if you have modeling questions they're better directed to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it just depends on the argument `len` of the function. For example, if I run the following code

```r
# packages
library(FLSSS)

# data
prof <- c(400, 320, 230, 210, 190, 130)
costs <- cbind(
  c(6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1), 
  c(8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4)
)

capac <- c(9, 18)
```

then I get your current optimal sack

```r
mmKnapsack(
  maxCore = 3, 
  len = 2, 
  itemsProfits = prof, 
  itemsCosts = costs, 
  capacities = capac
)
#> Updated profit = 720
#> $solution
#> [1] 2 1
#> 
#> $selectionCosts
#> [1]  9 16
#> 
#> $budgets
#> [1]  9 18
#> 
#> $selectionProfit
#> [1] 720
#> 
#> $unconstrainedMaxProfit
#> [1] 720
```

but if I increase the maximum subsize size (i.e. please note that I set `len = 3`), the I get another optimal solution.

```r
mmKnapsack(
  maxCore = 3, 
  len = 3, 
  itemsProfits = prof, 
  itemsCosts = costs, 
  capacities = capac
)
#> Updated profit = 630
#> Updated profit = 660
#> Updated profit = 720
#> Updated profit = 740
#> $solution
#> [1] 6 4 1
#> 
#> $selectionCosts
#> [1]  9 18
#> 
#> $budgets
#> [1]  9 18
#> 
#> $selectionProfit
#> [1] 740
#> 
#> $unconstrainedMaxProfit
#> [1] 950
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

From the [package docs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04484) you can read that if you set `len = 0`, then FLSSS function tries to look for the optimal solution for all subset sizes, i.e.

```r
mmKnapsack(
  maxCore = 3, 
  len = 0, 
  itemsProfits = prof, 
  itemsCosts = costs, 
  capacities = capac
)
#> Updated profit = 630
#> Updated profit = 740
#> $solution
#> [1] 1 4 6
#> 
#> $selectionCosts
#> [1]  9 18
#> 
#> $budgets
#> [1]  9 18
#> 
#> $selectionProfit
#> [1] 740
#> 
#> $unconstrainedMaxProfit
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful. I had assumed 'len' was the number of resources.